# How to create zoom-able pages in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to create a ViewPager which contains zoom-able views such as web pages.

My problem is :

When the user zooms (scales) the displayed view, the ViewPager should not fling to the pages on the left or right of the diplayed view, instead, the panning methods defined by me should work on that view. I am aware that there is a requestDisallowOnTouchIntercept method in view pager, but is does not seem to work anywhere instead of onTouch methods.

Kindly offer some valid solution.

Do not post [this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) as your answer

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an exact answer without knowing how you've implemented the zooming view, but assuming you have the ability to track whether or not your view is zoomed in you can selectively cancel the touch events before they reach the ViewPager. It'd look something like this:

```
boolean isZoomedIn;

viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (isZoomedIn)
        {
            // The view is zoomed in, so we want to handle this event 
            // before it gets to the ViewPager so the view can pan
            // around freely.
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // The view is zoomed out; let the ViewPager react normally.
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

You can get fancier from there, tracking whether or not your zoomed-in view is on the extreme left or right edge and then allowing the ViewPager's touch event to complete normally if the pointer's motion is going left or right, respectively. Then you can allow the user to swipe to the next page without requiring them to zoom out all the way again. You can learn all about how the touch is moving with the various properties on the MotionEvent object.

You may also want to check event.getPointerCount() and return True if it's greater than one, so the ViewPager won't move around while you're performing the zoom.

It gets a little complicated to track and account for all the variables, but it's relatively simple math and the result boils down to returning True for events you want the ViewPager to ignore and False for ones you want it to react to.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my problem was solved by viewPager.disallowOnTouchIntercept(true) which stops the viewPager from tracking my touch events when I don't want it to.